# How to disable right-click menu in terminal?

Tags: command-line, mouse, gnome-terminal

I'd like to disable right-mouse-click pop-up menu in Ubuntu terminal so that mouse right click to be passed to the application (Midnight Commander, to select files with the right mouse button). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

According to Gnome-Terminal's [Manual](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/2.29/gnome-terminal.html), there's no such function. You can always use another terminal emulator such as [xterm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xterm):

[image: selecting multiple folders via right click + drag in xterm]

This one doesn't have any sort of context menu. I've heard that you used to be able to do *<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click* in gnome-terminal, but it doesn't work (anymore).

Comment: Do you know of a corresponding bugtracker issue I can vote for?

Comment: I don't sorry, but I suppose this is a design decision, not a bug.

Comment: This was tracked in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13299, and fixed in vte-0.36 / gnome-terminal-3.12.